# На сервере Ubuntu 18.04 не виден сайт по ipv6 адресу

Tags: ubuntu, apache, dns, ipv6

На сервере Ubuntu 18.04 не виден сайт по ipv6 адресу.

`https://ipv4.sklad.rus/index.php` - работает

`https://ipv6.sklad.rus/index.php` - нет

Долго искал причину, не нашёл. Работает только в виртуальной винде.
Причина может быть где угодно, спрашивайте дополнительную информацию.

**Opera**

**This site can’t be reached**

The webpage at https://ipv6.sklad.rus/index.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT

---

**FireFox**

пустой экран

---

```
$ nslookup ipv6.sklad.rus
Server:         192.168.0.72
Address:        192.168.0.72#53

Name:   ipv6.sklad.rus
Address: fe80::5 (сетевая сервера II)
Name:   ipv6.sklad.rus
Address: fe80::9 (сетевая сервера I)
```

---

Виртуальная винда FireFox :

работает нормально

```
> nslookup ipv6.sklad.rus

?? : unknown
address : 192.168.0.72 (сервер)

?? : ipv6.sklad.rus
addresses : fe80::9 (сетевая сервера I)
            fe80::5 (сетевая сервера II)
```

---

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/sklad.rus.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin admin@sklad.rus
            ServerName sklad.rus
            ServerAlias ipv4.sklad.rus ipv6.sklad.rus
            DocumentRoot /var/www/sklad.rus/public_html

            <Directory />
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride None
            </Directory>
            <Directory  /var/www/sklad.rus/public_html>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64
                    allow from 192.168.0
                    allow from 192.168.1
                    allow from xxx.xxx
                    allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                    allow from 127.0.0.1
                    allow from xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::5
                    allow from fe80::/16
                    Require local
                    Require ip xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64
                    Require ip 192.168.0
                    Require ip 192.168.1
                    Require ip xxx.xxx
                    Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                    Require ip 127.0.0.1
                    Require ip xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::5
                    Require ip fe80::/16
           </Directory>
           ...
```

---

пингую

```
$ ping -I eth0 ipv6.sklad.rus
PING ipv6.sklad.rus(fe80::9 (fe80::9)) from fe80::948b:8c30:898f:e014%eth0 eth0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::9%eth0 (fe80::9%eth0): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.439 ms
64 bytes from fe80::9%eth0 (fe80::9%eth0): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.211 ms
...
```

трассирую

```
$ sudo traceroute -i eth0 ipv6.sklad.rus
traceroute to ipv6.sklad.rus (fe80::9), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  fe80::9%eth0 (fe80::9%eth0)  0.233 ms  0.141 ms  0.097 ms
```

на сервере `route` говорит :

```
$ route -6
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
localhost6.localdomain6/128    [::]                       U    256 1     0 lo
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64        [::]                       U    256 1     0 enp3s0
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64        [::]                       U    1024 1     0 enp2s0
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64        [::]                       U    1024 1     0 enp3s0
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    256 2     1 enp3s0
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    256 4   219 enp2s0
[::]/0                         fe80::6e3b:6bff:fedb:5ada  UG   1024 4  2434 enp2s0
[::]/0                         fe80::6e3b:6bff:fedb:5adc  UG   1024 4  2661 enp3s0
localhost6.localdomain6/128    [::]                       Un   0   5 21635 lo
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/128       [::]                       Un   0   2     0 enp2s0
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/128       [::]                       Un   0   2     0 enp3s0
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::5/128      [::]                       Un   0   2     0 enp3s0
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:523e:aaff:fe16:8646/128 [::]                       Un   0   2     0 enp3s0
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:ca60:ff:fe61:62c3/128 [::]                       Un   0   3  1176 enp2s0
fe80::/128                     [::]                       Un   0   2     0 enp3s0
fe80::/128                     [::]                       Un   0   2     0 enp2s0
sklad.rus/128                  [::]                       Un   0   3     1 enp3s0
sklad.rus/128                  [::]                       Un   0   5   268 enp2s0
fe80::523e:aaff:fe16:8646/128  [::]                       Un   0   4  7098 enp3s0
fe80::ca60:ff:fe61:62c3/128    [::]                       Un   0   3  4981 enp2s0
ff00::/8                       [::]                       U    256 4  6317 enp3s0
ff00::/8                       [::]                       U    256 4 54257 enp2s0
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1     5 lo
```

Comment: Так стоп, а откуда вы его пингуете и где пытаетесь открывать? Это всё в пределах какой-то локальной сети сидит?

Comment: В винде `netstat -p IPv6` показывает пустоту. А как в линуксе это сделать? @andreymal

Comment: Что пишет ` route -6`?

Comment: Могу сейчас сказать, только что сервер говорит. Посмотрите в обновлённый вопрос. @Pak Uula

Comment: Покажите таблицу маршрутизации на клиенте. Ну и до кучи вывод `ifconfig enp2s0` и `ifconfig enp2s0` на сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я могу судить, проблема в том, что вы используете link-local адрес. Для таких адресов не определена маршрутизация, ибо эти адреса есть в каждой локальной сети. Поэтому для взаимодействия с узлами по таким адресам необходимо явным образом указывать интерфейс, через который должны отправляться пакеты. В примере с `ping` вы задаёте интерфейс `-I eth0`. Что будет, если вы не укажете интерфейс? Скорее всего, пинг не пройдёт.

Попробуйте на клиенте прописать явную маршрутизацию для адресов сервера. Например, если клиент подключен к сети, в которой у сервера адрес `fe80::9`, сделать так: `sudo route -6 add fe80::9 dev eth0`. После этого клиент должен начать маршрутизировать адрес `fe80::9`

Но в общем и целом использовать link local адреса - плохая практика.

Я бы рекомендовал вам привязать доменное имя к адресу с глобальным префиксом. Насколько понимаю, такой префикс вы скрыли за иксами `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64`

Или же настройте себе внутренние адреса (ULA):

- придумайте себе для сервера два префикса из пространства ULA `fd00::`, например `fd00:a000::/48` и `fd00:b000::/48`
- присвойте серверу на каждую из сетевых карт адреса из этих префиксов (на одну карту адрес `fd00:a000::1`, на другую - `fd00:b000::1`),
- пропишите на клиенте правило маршрутизации для того префикса, к сети которого он подключен (например, `fd00:a000:: -> eth0`)
- пропишите адреса сервера в DNS или `/etc/hosts`

После этого адрес `fd00:a000::1` должен нормально маршрутизироваться на клиенте и сервер должен стать доступным.

Comment: внутренние адреса и хотел сделать, только как `fe80` в чём разница, если я заменю на `fd00` ? С маршрутизацией на всех клиентах, я потренируюсь в рабочее время.

Comment: `fe80` - это очень специальный префикс. Он обрабатывается особым образом, и если на машине более одного сетевого интерфейса, то по умолчанию маршрутизация таких адресов не определена. Нужно либо явно указывать _зону_ (идентификатор сетевой карты - `fe80::9%eth0`) либо явно прописывать маршрут в таблице маршрутизации. Префиксы, начинающиеся с `fc00/7` подчиняются нормальным правилам маршрутизации, за исключением того, что шлюзы не должны пересылать внаружу пакеты, адресованные на эти префиксы.

Comment: долго ковырялся, решалось только при полной перегрузки сервера и клиентов. Поставил белые адреса "2a03:...". Одна старинная установка клиента пашет только с **ipv4.**

Comment: В сумме : `/etc/hosts` поставил белые адреса, в `/bind/` белые адреса. В `/dhcp/` убрал как главного роутера Mikrotik, поставил как главный роутер сам сервер. `ipv6.` адреса видны везде.

Comment: С адресами `fd00` получилось. В роутере Mikrotik `IPv6`.`Routes` добавил адреса  `fd00:a000::/64` , `fd00:b000::/64` с EUI64. Роутер разрешает только `/64`, и везде поставил эту маску. В клиентах маршрутизацию не надо было, всё стало Plug&Play.

Answer (score 1):

На сервере Ubuntu 18.04 не виден сайт по ipv6 адресу.

основные моменты для проверки
1 на сервере должен быть айпи 6 адрес видимый из внешней сети
2 у регистратора ДИ должен быть прописан тот же ай пи 6 адрес что и на сервере  ipv6.sklad.rus === 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 ( ето как пример
3 апач или нгинкс должен быть настроен на прием и разруливание ай пи 6 адресов 80 или 443 порт приводящий к ipv6.sklad.rus ==> /home/sklad/web/public_html

иногда идут проглючки и надо указать что то вида
2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334:443 вместо *:443

ето основные рекомендации ..... в любом месте может быть затык
условно если идет запрос из АФРИКИ ( и там толко ай пи 4 сетки .... то ресолв по ай пи 6 ты не получиш.

Comment: `/var/log/apache2/access.log` содержит `fe80::ad8f:5208:ed64:d228 - - [09/Oct/2021:11:27:07 +0200] "GET /menu.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2140 "https://ipv6.sklad.rus/php/souz.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0"` это говорит после винды. Внешний IP кажется не нужен.